# transform grammar problem

Tags: context-free-grammar

```
S -> aB | lamda
B -> bB
```

B is a useless production. Now after its removal

```
S -> a | lamda
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

production S -> aB does not terminate. Because B -> bB does not terminate. So the production S -> aB is useless.

the answer should be

```
S -> lambda
```

Answer (score 1):

Boy it's been a *long* time since I've looked at CFG's.  B produces an infinite series of b's, does it not (b*?)

Assuming b* means an infinite series of B's I think I would reduce to:

S -> ab* | λ

**EDIT:**

Yes, my answer above is wrong.  The definition of a "useless production" is a production that is never used in the derivation of a terminal string.  Since B is non-terminal it can be removed thus S -> λ.

+1 to the answer by user574183.